# possible refactor? long repeating lines of codes java

Tags: java, refactoring

Hiii. So I have these really long switch-case, and I have these codes:

```
case 34:
            if(cToken.getName() == TokenName.PROG_NAME.toString() 
                || cToken.getName() == "DEDENT"
                || cToken.getName() == TokenName.ASSIGN.toString()
                || cToken.getName() == TokenName.PROC_CALL.toString()
                || cToken.getName() == TokenName.BREAK.toString()
                || cToken.getName() == TokenName.CONTINUE.toString()
                || cToken.getName() == TokenName.DATATYPE_BOOL.toString()
                || cToken.getName() == TokenName.DATATYPE_CHAR.toString()
                || cToken.getName() == TokenName.DATATYPE_FLOAT.toString()
                || cToken.getName() == TokenName.DATATYPE_INT.toString()
                || cToken.getName() == TokenName.DATATYPE_STRING.toString()
                || cToken.getName() == TokenName.DATATYPE_VOID.toString()
                || cToken.getName() == TokenName.INPUT.toString()
                || cToken.getName() == TokenName.OUTPUT.toString()
                || cToken.getName() == TokenName.IF.toString()
                || cToken.getName() == TokenName.DO.toString()
                || cToken.getName() == TokenName.WHILE.toString()
                || cToken.getName() == TokenName.INC_OP.toString()
                || cToken.getName() == TokenName.DEC_OP.toString()){
                    reduce(51);
            } else {
                error();
            } break;
case 35:
            if(cToken.getName() == TokenName.PROG_NAME.toString() 
                || cToken.getName() == "DEDENT"
                || cToken.getName() == TokenName.ASSIGN.toString()
                || cToken.getName() == TokenName.PROC_CALL.toString()
                || cToken.getName() == TokenName.BREAK.toString()
                || cToken.getName() == TokenName.CONTINUE.toString()
                || cToken.getName() == TokenName.DATATYPE_BOOL.toString()
                || cToken.getName() == TokenName.DATATYPE_CHAR.toString()
                || cToken.getName() == TokenName.DATATYPE_FLOAT.toString()
                || cToken.getName() == TokenName.DATATYPE_INT.toString()
                || cToken.getName() == TokenName.DATATYPE_STRING.toString()
                || cToken.getName() == TokenName.DATATYPE_VOID.toString()
                || cToken.getName() == TokenName.INPUT.toString()
                || cToken.getName() == TokenName.OUTPUT.toString()
                || cToken.getName() == TokenName.IF.toString()
                || cToken.getName() == TokenName.DO.toString()
                || cToken.getName() == TokenName.WHILE.toString()
                || cToken.getName() == TokenName.INC_OP.toString()
                || cToken.getName() == TokenName.DEC_OP.toString()){
                    reduce(52);
            } else {
                error();
            } break;
```

ok, so that's just two of the cases I have. I was just wondering if there's a way where I can make/use a shortcut for that long expression (which repeats) but because I use them in different cases, with different -to do- (if it passes the 'if' test e.g (case 34, call reduce method with 51 as input and case 35, call reduce method with 52 as input)

Basically, what I'm askin is if there's a way where I could like put

```
cToken.getName() == TokenName.PROG_NAME.toString() 
|| cToken.getName() == "DEDENT"
|| cToken.getName() == TokenName.ASSIGN.toString()
|| cToken.getName() == TokenName.PROC_CALL.toString()
|| cToken.getName() == TokenName.BREAK.toString()
|| cToken.getName() == TokenName.CONTINUE.toString()
|| cToken.getName() == TokenName.DATATYPE_BOOL.toString()
|| cToken.getName() == TokenName.DATATYPE_CHAR.toString()
|| cToken.getName() == TokenName.DATATYPE_FLOAT.toString()
|| cToken.getName() == TokenName.DATATYPE_INT.toString()
|| cToken.getName() == TokenName.DATATYPE_STRING.toString()
|| cToken.getName() == TokenName.DATATYPE_VOID.toString()
|| cToken.getName() == TokenName.INPUT.toString()
|| cToken.getName() == TokenName.OUTPUT.toString()
|| cToken.getName() == TokenName.IF.toString()
|| cToken.getName() == TokenName.DO.toString()
|| cToken.getName() == TokenName.WHILE.toString()
|| cToken.getName() == TokenName.INC_OP.toString()
|| cToken.getName() == TokenName.DEC_OP.toString()
```

to a variable or some placeholder and then use that variable in the if-clause so that long block of code only appears once, and then I'm just gonna use the variable that contains that?

Sorry if I can't explain better.. Thank you!

Comment: Don't compare Strings using `==` or `!=`. Use the `equals(...)` or the `equalsIgnoreCase(...)` method instead. Understand that `==` checks if the two *object references* are the same which is not what you're interested in. The methods on the other hand check if the two Strings have the same characters in the same order, and that's what matters here.

Comment: Ohhh, right. Thank you for the tip! I'll fix them right away :)

Comment: Seems like you should have `switch-case` under that `if` condition, rather than the opposite Also, it's not a good idea to have 35 cases in a `switch`. Try devising a way to club them all together in few lines of code (which will almost always be possible).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider putting your Strings in a collection such as an ArrayList or HashSet, and then seeing if the String of interest is contained in the collection via the `contains(String)` method.

As a side recommendation, don't compare Strings using `==` or `!=`. Use the `equals(...)` or the `equalsIgnoreCase(...)` method instead. Understand that `==` checks if the two *object references* are the same which is not what you're interested in. The methods on the other hand check if the two Strings have the same characters in the same order, and that's what matters here.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the value passed to `reduce` is 17 more than the `case` label.

You can make sure that the value you're switching on is within the range you need, then pass `value + 17` to `reduce`.

```
if (value >= x && value <= y)
{
     if (/* really long conditions here */)
     {
         reduce(value + 17);
     }
}
```

If there isn't a mathematical relationship between the case label and the value passed to `reduce` (and the "plus 17" was just a coincidence for the 2 cases you showed), then create a `Map<Integer, Integer>` of case labels to reduce values to be used when calling `reduce`.

That will eliminate the need to copy the long `if` conditions over and over again for each case.

Second, place all possible values for `getName()` in a `List<String>` and call `contains` to see if it matches one of them.

```
     if (listOfValues.contains(cToken.getName()) {
```

Comment: Hi! Can you please elaborate more on the Map<Integer, Integer> idea? Thank you!

Comment: You could place integer pairs into the `Map` beforehand, e.g. `put(34, 51); put(35, 52); put(1, 99);`.  Then, if your conditions are met, just call `reduce(myMap.get(value));`.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a List with acceptable tokens

```
List<String> tokens = Arrays.asList(TokenName.PROG_NAME.toString(), "DECENT", ...);
```

and then check with

```
tokens.contains(cToken.getName())
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you add a method `getReductionFactor()` to your TokenName class?  Then just call

```
reduce(value + cToken.getReductionFactor());
```

and be done with it.

Comment: what would that method contain though? Sorry.

Comment: You could add a private final reductionFactor field to the TokenName class, initialize it in the constructor, and return it in the getter.